# How to provide a user guide?

Tags: android, user-guide

I have been trying to find the answer to this question on both the Google developer site and here on SO but so far am unable to come up with a satisfactory answer.

I wish to provide users that download my application with a "user guide" on how to set-up certain parts of the application and how to load external data into it. I would like to add some screenshots in a simple step-by-step guide.

Is there a fixed framework available to do this? I could ship the app with a few pages that I load in the device's browser - but on a phone browser - looking at a screenshot of a phone may not be very "readable". Would a URL that one could view from a PC be better? Or perhaps just a textwindow within my application would be best. I was hoping someone here has had an idea that may have worked well for them in the past.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I would just host the user guide online and provide a link to it from your app.

It would be easiest to set up and it allows to user to view the guide from their computer or tablet.  (This way they can set up your app without having to switch back and forth between your guide and the relevant screen!)

Comment: +1, just add an activity with a webview to your app, so you can simply create a nice looking user guide in html.